# Angular login with azure adfs and springboot api

Tags: java, azure, java-11, angular11, spring-boot-starter-security

I have a webapp in angular 11 and the backend with springboot 2.4.4. I use JWT for login and the users are in the db but now I have to change to login with azure adfs. I have not idea how do it. I read and tried loging in angular, but i don't know how login in angular with azure and use this token in the springboot security back. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

We could use [Authorization Code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) for a webapp with angular and the backend with springboot.

There is a [demo](https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html#the-azure-ad-part) using Angular app as **Client** and Spring Boot app as **Resource Server**. [Code](https://github.com/jmeys/azure-ad-demo-backend) in github .